# Print the labels and values of textareas/inputs which are in a spezific area of a form

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the label and values of some of my textareas and input-tags, which I have on my website. There are many inputs/textereas and I dont want to have all of them, only the textareas/inputs in a spezific area. For example in the following case, I only want to have all values that came after the texterea with the name b:

```js
var inputs;

$('textarea').each(function(){
  var name= $(this).attr('name');
  inputs += name+': '+$(this).val()+'<br>';

 })

document.write(inputs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method='post' action="/form">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_a</label>
  <textarea  name="a" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_b</label>
  <textarea name="b"  class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
 </div>         
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_c</label>
  <textarea  name="c" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
 </div>        
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_d</label>
  <textarea  name="d" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
 </div>
</form>
```

But that is not the whole problem. Instead of the name, I want to have the lable of the input/textarea. Have I to add a for-attribut to each control and label to do that or is there a easier way to do that?

Can sombody say, why it first print "undefined"?

I would be very lucky if somebody can help me :)

Comment: it first prints 'undefined' since you never initialize it with a value or an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize `inputs`, then check if the name is after 'b' if you only want sections after that, and to get the label text use `$(this).prev().text()`

```js
var after='b';
var inputs='';
var found=false;

$('textarea').each(function(index){
  if(found){
var name= $(this).prev().text();
inputs += name+': '+$(this).val()+'<br>';
  }
  if($(this).attr('name')==after)
found=true;
});

document.write(inputs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method='post' action="/form">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_a</label>
  <textarea  name="a" class="form-control" rows="1">this is content of a</textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_b</label>
  <textarea name="b"  class="form-control" rows="1">this is content of b</textarea>
 </div>         
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_c</label>
  <textarea  name="c" class="form-control" rows="1">this is content of c</textarea>
 </div>        
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">label_d</label>
  <textarea  name="d" class="form-control" rows="1">this is content of d</textarea>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ok thank you so far. But "> b" gives me only the labels from inputs which name starts with c or d or e etc. My problem was that I need the inputs which comes after the input b. you can substitute the name b with k or somithing.

Comment: @nina_berlini so its the sections after 'b' or 'k' regardless of `name`?

Comment: @nina_berlini how do you decide or choose which section you want sections after?

Comment: all inputs which comes next to b (but theirs names can start with an "a" of course) I would like to have. my english isn't so good. I hope you can understand my problem

Comment: @nina_berlini do you specify `b` or whatever to come after? or is it after the second or the last two sections or something else?

Comment: we need an example: <input name=alex> <input name=michael> <input name=anna> <input name=richard> (I know the syntax isnt correct, its only pseudo code) and I want to have all inputs after michael, in this case it is anna and richard.

Answer (score 0):

just initialize the inputs.

```
var inputs = "";
```

Update:

to use the labels as the name, change the var name to the following:

```
var name= $(this).parent().find('label').html();
```

Comment: that doesn't answer all of the OP questions

Comment: to get the label you could shorten it to `$(this).prev().text()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use parent()

```
var inputs = "";
$('textarea').each(function(){
    var name_label = $(this).parent().find('label').text();
    var values = $(this).val();
    console.log(name_label + " : " + values);
    inputs+=name_label + " : "+ values;
});
document.write(inputs);
```

And if you want another text from another tag, you replace label for the tag, example, span, p , div etc.